# PhoneRTC support for browsers

Tags: phonertc

I could deploy demo https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/ and connected mobile devices Android/Android and Android/IOS. But not clear how to connect mobile device with browser. I'm tryied to use PhoneRTCProxy.js but still without success. If any body have solution let me know please.

Comment: I could resolve issue. I just added browser platform and it start work with my implementation as i have for mobile.  **cordova platform add browser**  /  **cordova run browser**

Comment: Did you really get it to working ? My side I could establish the call but video does not appear  Getting this error     TypeError: Cannot read property 'receiveMessage' of undefined

Comment: Yes I could make it work. just followed the ttps://github.com/alongubkin guide. At least i could connect IOS and Android with browser version.

Comment: is it possible for you to share your build app for browser ucdevinda@gmail.com

Comment: Sorry man. That is not possible. I deploy on test amazon account it not exist any more. If you could start rtc for Android or IOS, Just compile everything for browser pltform using "cordova run browser" then deploy to web.

Comment: Ok mate no problem I will try to figure our something cheers !!!!